# Add a circular line chart inside a circular chart point with different magnitude data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a file called mitodata that has 8388 rows and I writed an exemple to explain my problem:

```
mitodata <-"Chr gene bp foldchange p
chrM chrM-1-2 2 -1.5 0.02
chrM chrM-3-4 4 1.5 0.05
chrM chrM-5-6 6 -1.2 0.0005
chrM chrM-7-8 8 1.3 0.02
chrM chrM-9-10 10 -1.6 0.007"
mitodata<-read.table(text=mitodata,header=T)
```

I can easily add some informations to this data to be used to plot a circular graph showing my p-value in a Manhattan plot manner, using ggplot2 as follow:

```
# Load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

#First adding a label for this exemple:  
addgenelabel <- function(bp,gene) { gene <- ifelse(bp < 2, gene <- "Control-Region", ifelse(bp < 4, gene <- "tRNA", ifelse (bp < 6, gene <- "12S", ifelse(bp < 8, gene <- "tRNA", ifelse(bp < 10, gene <- "16S", gene <- "Control-Region")))))}

# Add gene names to each SNP
    mitodata$gene <- addgenelabel(mitodata$bp,mitodata$gene)     
    # Creates and stores negative log p as a new variable
    mitodata$neglogp <- -1*log10(mitodata$p)
    # Adds a significance threshold line at negative log of 0.05
    mitodata$neglogpline <- -1*log10(0.05)
    # Adds -3 label to y axis
    mitodata$extraline <- -3
    # Set colors for each gene
    colours <- c("Control-Region" <- "deeppink", "tRNA" <- "green", "12S" <- "mediumaquamarine", "16S" <- "sienna4","red")

    lines <- data.frame(x = seq(0,10,by=1),y = 0)
    lines$gene <- addgenelabel(lines$x,lines$gene)
```

And after this, I can plot using this command:

```
# Plot everything and GO
      p<- ggplot(mitodata, aes(x = bp,y = neglogp,color = gene)) +
      geom_point(size=0.5, alpha=1)+ coord_polar(direction = -1) +
      geom_line(aes(x,1.30,color = "black"),data = lines, linetype="dotted") +
      #facet_grid(.~pheno) +
      geom_line(aes(y=extraline)) +
      geom_point(aes(x,y,color = gene),data=lines, size=2) +
      scale_colour_manual(values = colours,"Genes",breaks = c("Control-Region","tRNA","12S","16S"),
      labels = c("Control-Region","tRNA","12S","16S")) + 
      theme(legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position=c(0.98,0.98)) + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=10)) +
      xlab("Mitochondrial CpG Location") +
      ylab("-log(p-value)") +
      ggtitle("Negative Log P-value of Mitochondrial CpG Hits")


      ggsave("solarplot.tiff", w=12, h=12, dpi=600, compression = "lzw")
```

Doing it, using my 8388 rows of data, I obtained a graph like this:[image]

After I converted p value, using negative log of p, p-value and foldchange were in the same magnitude. Thus, when plotting the graph, both overlaped. The issue is that I would like to add an inside line chart to this graph showing the fold change column information but not overlapping with the p-value information. Something like this:

obs: would be nice to have this chart changing the colors according to the defined "gene" across the circle
[image]

Comment: unrelated, but use `cut` or `case_when` rather than nested `ifelse` statements

Comment: Your question is not very clear now (probably that's why it didn't get that much attention). Can you add more data; simplify code (I don't understand why you need function `addgenelabel`) just add data and plot code; and explain at which exact position you want to add feature; also how can p.value and FC be on the same scale?

Comment: Thanks PoGibas,edited!
Actually, by converting p-value, I ended up putting p-value and foldchange on the same scale. And then the two overlapped.
To fix it, I subtracted all the foldchange values from 3 and got an internal plot of foldchange on the circle. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe use dedicated package: http://zuguang.de/circlize/